# How to monitor the integrity of a script that is running?

Tags: cron, python, checksum

I want to make sure a running python script was not modified accidentally by some other process (or cosmic ray, or unexpected developer update). I've heard of comparing a checksum of the script (e.g. with `md5sum`) against a known value stored in a write-protected file but am unsure how to get the checksum of a file that's in use.  **Is the memory of the script that is being executed my actual source file?**  Or is what is being executed somewhere else?

Here is what I've tried so far, but don't know if my result is valid.

#### 1. Create a write-protected file containing the checksum

```
cd ~/Developer/MyProj
# Compute the md5 hash and store it in a new file
md5sum /home/username/Developer/MyProj/myscript.py > checksum
# Remove the write permissions for all (user, group, and other)
chmod a-w checksum
# Inspect the permissions to validate
ls -al checksum
```

#### 2. Add cronjob to periodically (e.g. hourly) check the integrity of the script

```
sudo crontab -e
0     *     *     *     * /bin/sh /home/username/Developer/MyProj/healthcheck.sh
```

In `healthcheck.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

s1=$(md5sum /home/username/Developer/MyProj/myscript.py)
s2=$(cat /home/username/Developer/MyProj/checksum)

if [ "$s1"="$s2" ]
then
  echo "Script is what we think it is"
else
  echo "Script was modified!"
fi
```

Comment: That seems like it would work.  Whether the file is being executed at the time or not isn't really part of the equation because the checksum is generated based on the file (or the data within the file).  If the file is changed and the changes written to disk, the checksum changes and your script should drop into "Script was modified!".  Now I don't know if your script is written well enough that it will work - it looks like it to to me, but I'm no scripting guru.  All I'm saying is that the theory that you're running on seems sound based on what I know of checksums.